# Como preencher com zeros a esquerda em Python?

Tags: python, formatação

Em php, sei que podemos preencher um número com zeros através do `printf`

Exemplo:

```
printf('%04s', 4); // Imprime: "0004"
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso em `Python`?

Quando tento fazer isso da maneira acima, o resultado não é o esperado:

```
print '%04s' % 4; #Imprime: \t\t\t\t4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode usar o método que o @WallaceMaxters demonstrou:

```
>>> print '%05d' % 4
'00004'
```

Outra possibilidade é usar o método `zfill` da classe `str`, o [str.zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill), mas para isso você precisará que a entrada seja uma string, pois este método simplesmente completa strings até o tamanho especificado no parâmetro `width`:

```
>>> print '4'.zfill(5)
'00004'
>>> print str(4).zfill(5)
'00004'
>>> print 'xpto'.zfill(5)
0xpto
```

Ou por fim utilizar o método de formatação da classe str, o [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Veja alguns exemplos:

```
>>> print '{:0>5}'.format(4)
'00004'
>>> print '{:0<5}'.format(4)
'40000'
>>> print '{:0^5}'.format(4)
'00400'
```

Um exemplo mais completo para você ter uma idéia do que o `format` pode fazer:

```
>>> pessoa = {"nome": "Fernando", "usuario": "fgmacedo"}
>>> print '<a href="{p[usuario]}/">{p[nome]} ({0} pontos)</a>'.format(4, p=pessoa)
<a href="fgmacedo/">Fernando (4 pontos)</a>
```

Eu acho o `format` mais elegante e poderoso. Você pode ler a especificação completa da linguagem de formatação que o `str.format` utiliza em [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Não querendo ser troll, mas eu sou o @WallaceMaxters :)  (o que perguntou e o que respondeu)

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer isso em `Python`, é necessário utilizar o argumento de formatação `d`.

Veja:

```
print '%04d' % 4 #Imprime: 0004
```

`%` - é o modificador

`0` - é o valor que vai ser usado no preenchimento

`4` - é a quantidade utilizada para preencher com um determinado valor, declarado anteriormente a ele (nesse caso o 0).

Assim sendo, se quiséssemos preencher com 8 zeros, faríamos:

```
print '%08d' % 4; #Imprime: 00000004 só aumentando a quantidade de zeros sem mudar o valor
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando **f-strings** (strings literais) cuja documentação se encontram [aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) e [aqui](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#formatspec), podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
a = 4
print(f'{a:04}')
```

Executando este código receberemos a seguinte saída:

```
0004
```

Então, os valores numéricos terão o número de dígitos - que neste caso é 4 - completados com zeros à esquerda.